# Check DVD region code from command line

Tags: linux, command-line, dvd, regional-settings

Is there a way to get DVD region code from command line (linux/ubuntu 9.10)?
I want to script this action and store the region code (and other data about DVD) in a log.

EDIT:
I am looking for the info about media, not the drive.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [source code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/mydvdregion.aspx) of a project that claims to be able to get the code.  I understand that it will not work in your environment but there seem to be some good references at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although it's hardly an answer to link to some non-portable code when asked for a CLI tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to check the region code of your DVD *Drive*, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/933178) askubuntu post suggests that there is a dedicated command line utility for it:

> `sudo apt install regionset`
>
> insert a cd or dvd and ...
>
> ```
> $ regionset
> regionset version 0.1 -- reads/sets region code on DVD drives
> Current Region Code settings:
> RPC Phase: II
> type: NONE
> vendor resets available: 4
> user controlled changes resets available: 5
> drive plays discs from region(s):, mask=0xFF
> ```

If all you are looking to do is see the region code of the DVD itself, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/677160) post may be helpful:

> If you have the DVD inserted and start VLC from command line it will show it.